How do I translate a phrase referring to a "flashy" fighting style into German?
I am trying to translate a line in a video game where the player attempts to pick up a shield and is informed that it is "certainly too big to fit with your 'flashy heroine' fighting style." The implication is that it weighs so much that she would not be able to do her usual combat maneuvers with it, e.g. dodging or doing flips. I am not sure how to translate the phrase "'flashy heroine' fighting style;" something tells me that "Auffällige-Heldin-Kampfstil" would be awkward.
Is there a way to translate this directly, or do I need to change it to something like "too big to fit with your flashy fighting style" (zu groß, um zu deinem auffälligen Kampfstil zu passen)?

If you translate flashy heroine literally as strahlende Heldin, you might be getting somewhere.

Maybe also consider constructions like „Dieser Schild ist zu groß für den Kampfstil einer auffälligen Heldin“ (though I agree about translating flashy differently)

What is your understanding of "flashy heroine" style in English? Can you describe more if you have a clear vision what attributes are associated with this phrasing?
What I would connect to flashy maybe is kind of speed light or fast fighting...

It's not clear to me without context whether the "flashy heroine style" is meant to be ironic or not (I guess it somewhat is).
Flashy doesn't necessarily need to be translated close to the dictionary with "auffällig" - Take it (somewhat) literally as "strahlend". This would also put it a bit into the tounge-in-cheek region like the original.
So

certainly too big to fit with your 'flashy heroine' fighting style.

would be translated as

mit Sicherheit zu groß für deinen 'Strahlende-Heldin'-Kampfstil.


Mit heldenhaft strahlenden Kampfstil umginge man die ungelenk wirkende Substantivierung. Die Apostrophe scheinen mir völlig fehl am Platze (auch schon im Englischen) und müssten m.E., wenn, dann auch den Kampfstil umfassen.

@userunknown Über die Apostrophe habe ich tatsächlich eine Weile nachgedacht. Den Kampfstil in die Klammern zu nehmen, halte ich für übertrieben - Schließlich ist genau der wörtlich gemeint. Wo siehst du eine Substantivierung?

In der Durchkopplung mit Bindestrichen "Strahlende-Heldin-Kampfstil" sehe ich eine Substantivierung. Apostrophe sind Auslassungszeichen und keine Ironiemarker. Wenn man stattdessen das Wort kursiv setzt, weil man den Lesern sonst die Ironieerkennung nicht zutraut (das hier Ironie ausgedrückt werden soll ist jedoch nicht gesichert) - wobei Ironie versteckter Spott ist, eine Auszeichnung jedoch das Gegenteil von Verstecken ist - setzt man das ganze Wort kursiv, nicht nur Fragmente. Quelle: https://www.belleslettres.eu/content/zeichensetzung/anfuhrungszeichen.php @49:09 ca. 10 Min.

@userunknown "strahlend" ist ein Adjektiv. Sowohl "Heldin" als auch "Kampfstil" sind Substantive. Selbst wenn ich die Augen stark Zusammenklemme, kann ich keine Substantivierung erkennen. Deine Ausführung zum Thema "Ironie", die "versteckt werden muß", kann ich nicht ganz nachvollziehen (außer, das ist in sich schon versteckte Ironie. Dann würde mir eine Auszeichnung sehr helfen)

It depends on whether you mean to mock her or not. Schrill would be an adjective that fits flashy for mocking purposes. It means that she has an unnecessarily colorful costume with a lot of useless ornaments. But it could also mean that she yells at her enemies a lot. “Kiiiiyyyaaaaaah!”
… certainly too big to fit with your 'flashy heroine' fighting style.

… ganz sicher zu klobig für den von dir bevorzugten Kampfstil „Die schrille Amazone“.

Other options:

„Die überdrehte Schraube“
„Die nervige Wespe“

If you don't want to mock her, other options for the fighting stlye are

„Die leichtfüßige Gazelle“
„Die flinke Heuschrecke“

